# TTK cannot change state button before executing a cycle

Tags: python, button, state, status, ttk

I'm learning Python by myself and I'm playing with ttk library.

I'm stuck in a problem regarding the change of status of the buttons.
In particular, if I change the status of the button from disabled to enabled and then I put a for-cycle, the for-cycle is executed before the status change.

In this piece of program, I wanna change the status of ReceiveButton and StopButton, then print a time count on the screen. If I execute the code, I see the count on the screen and only at the end the status of the buttons change.

I'm a little surprised, what is the problem?

```
ReceiveButton.state(['pressed'])
StopButton.state(['!disabled'])
    for i in range (1, 3):
        sleep(1)
        print(i)
    return
```

Comment: What happened to the "Python" tag I added to this question?

Comment: your code never gives tkinter a chance to update the screen. `sleep` does exactly what it says, it puts the whole program to sleep. There are many, many questions relate to using sleep with tkinter, and for updating widgets in a loop.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. I understood the problem.